# How to effectively export Math equations from Microsoft word to HTML

Tags: html, ms-word

I blog about computer vision and involves good amount of math. I find myself comfortable using Microsoft Word to prepare the write-up before posting.

1. I haven't figured an effectively way to move the Math equations in
   the Word document to the blog. I want it to be rendered as text. What options do I have ?
2. I did come across 'MathJax' here in the Math section. Is it possible to use
   it as a plugin in Blogger?

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII codes, search for the equivalent of a math equation. Ex. 10 `&gt;` 11. It will render as 10 < 11.

Comment: Thank.. wonder if there are tools instead of 'writing' maths in ASCII?